# Find the subspace $S$ to maximize the function $J=\frac{Tr(P_{S}A)}{Tr(P_{S}B)}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

Let $A$ and $B$ be two synmetric matrices, $B$ is positive and $A$ is non-negtive. Surpose a $k$ dimentional space $S\subset R^{n}$ , and let $P_S$ be its orthogonal projection matrix.

QUESTION: Find the subspace $S$ to maximize the function $J=\frac{Tr(P_{S}A)}{Tr(P_{S}B)}$

PS: Let $\lambda _1 \ge\lambda_2 \ge \cdots \ge \lambda _n $ be the generalized eigenvalues of $(A,B)$, and $p_1, p_2, \cdots ,p_n$ are the coresponding eigenvectors. I guess the space $span\{p_1,p_2, \cdots , p_k\}$ is the solution. But I cannot prove it.

Answer (score 0):

A very partial answer. Of course, those who placed "on hold" your question on MO know the answer (at least, I hope so...).

Up to an orthonormal change of basis, $P_S=diag(I_k,0_{n-k}),A=\begin{pmatrix}K&L\\M&N\end{pmatrix}$; then $tr(P_SA)=tr(K)=\sum_{i=1}^ke_i^TAe_i$, where $(e_i)_i$ is the (orthonormal) canonical basis. Then $\sup_S\dfrac{tr(P_SA)}{tr(P_SB)}=\sup_{S}\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^ku_i^TAu_i}{\sum_{i=1}^ku_i^TBu_i}$, where $(u_i)_i$ is an orthonormal basis of $S$.

If $k=1$, then $\sup_S\dfrac{tr(P_SA)}{tr(P_SB)}=\sup_{u\not=0}\dfrac{u^TAu}{u^TBu}=\lambda_1$ is reached when $u=p_1$.

If $k\geq 2$, then it is not clear because the $(p_i)_i$ are not orthogonal vectors.

Comment: This is my first time to ask a question onSE and you are the first one who answer my question. Thank you very much.